# Having trouble using “rSection” or “rSubsection"

Tags: errors, resume, cv

In a resume I wanted to write in LaTeX, I am getting a strange error when I use the `rSection` as below:

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins

\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
\name{Shakiba } % Your name

%\address{The address} % Your address

\begin{document}
\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bf University Of California-Riverside} \hfill {\em Date} 

\\{\bf University of Tehran} \hfill {\em Date} 
\\ Bachelor of Physics\\
\\Department of Physics

end{rSection}
\end{document}
```

The Error says:

> Environment rSection undefined.

Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code:

```
{\bf University Of California-Riverside} \hfill {\em Date} 

\\{\bf University of Tehran} \hfill {\em Date}
```

The blank line causes an error, delete it and

```
end{rSection}
```

Here is the leading `\` missing.

With the corrected code

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins

\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
\name{Shakiba } % Your name

%\address{The address} % Your address

\begin{document}
\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bf University Of California-Riverside} \hfill {\em Date} 
\\{\bf University of Tehran} \hfill {\em Date} 
\\ Bachelor of Physics\\
\\Department of Physics

\end{rSection} % <======================================================
\end{document}
```

I get the result

[image]

with using class `resume` (Medium Length Professional CV - RESUME CLASS FILE) from www.LaTeXTemplates.com.